# jQuery filtering results - stange matching

Tags: jquery, filter, contains

I'm using jQuery to filter a tables rows and it works.

But I've noticed in a very specific way it find a match it shouldn't.

This is my jQuery:

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
    var rows = $(".rows").find('tr').hide();
    var data = this.value.split("/");
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        rows.filter(":Contains('" + v + "')").show();
    });
});

jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function(elem) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

This is my data:

```
John Smith  4500
Mike Green  1234
David Brown 8542
ID5004  5004
Mal Smith   6532
```

If I search for 1234, I get only 1234..  If I search for 4500 I get 4500 & 5004.

I think the issue is due to the inner text being read and that is matching on:

John Smith  **4500**

ID500**4    500**4

I still want to be able to search across all fields, but is it possible to limit the match so it doesn't find entries like this ?

I've created a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsef5bLj/3/)** that shows the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `jQuery(elem).text()` it concatenates the text of the two tr tds without space.
You can check for each td of the tr instead.
https://jsfiddle.net/ktriek/bsef5bLj/6/

```
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
return function( elem ) {     
  var tds = jQuery(elem).find('td');
  return tds.eq(0).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0 ||
  tds.eq(1).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
});
```

Comment: This would allow people to match on the HTML of the element though, eg. searching `td` would return everything.

Comment: +1, although note that you can make the check more robust by using `filter()`, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4g97dpm5/1/

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This solution seems to be working for me.